# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'placeholder' with version -1

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am building a model for Text summarization and using Tensorflow 2.3.0.
I am getting errors for placeholders.

```py
def model_inputs():
    """Create placeholders for inputs to the model."""

    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='input')
    targets = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, None], name='targets')
    lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='learning_rate')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')
    summary_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None,), name='summary_length')
    max_summary_length = tf.reduce_max(summary_length, name='max_dec_len')
    text_length = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None,), name='text_length')

    return input_data, targets, lr, keep_prob, summary_length, max_summary_length, text_length
```

To overcome this I used

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

and got this error:

> Module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

If I use tensorflow version 2 it gives a "placeholder" error and if use version 1 I get a "contrib" error.

How do I handle these errors?

Comment: Why are you using `tf.placeholder` in tensorflow 2.0+ ?

Comment: TensorFlow 2.3.0 was installed on my machine. when I tried to build a model I got to know this. so I disable its behavior. but then I am getting an error for "contrib" which is not in version 1.
Note: I am using tensorflow for the first time for building summarization model.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are using `TF 1.x` api into `TF 2.x` which is deprecated to use in `TF 2.x` and replaced with **tf.keras.Input()** . You either need to use **tf.keras.Input()** in place of [tf.placeholder()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/placeholder) to run your code in `TF 2.x` or you need to select `TensorFlow version 1.x` to use **tf.placeholder()** api.

To select `TF 1.x` without changing the code, You can write `%tensorflow_version 1.x` on top of all your code and execute this line of code. You may get output as `TensorFlow 1.x selected`. Now you can run your code successfully without any error.